# Running multiple Javascript png sprite animations simultaneously

Tags: javascript, animation, png, sprite

I've been requested to create a simple png animation: a glint that appears when hovering over menu items as seen here: http://www.breathoflifeart.com/wordpress/videos/
As you can see at time of posting, the animation plays fine, but stops in place when another instance starts (sweep the mouse over the menu entries at a moderate speed to see the bug)
I'm trying to either:
A. Let the animation play through even after another element is highlighted
or
B. Reset the background-position to 0 onmouseout

Here's the current javascript, modified from an example found in another question:

```
var scrollUp = (function () {
var timerId; // stored timer in case you want to use clearInterval later
return function (height, times, element) {
        clearInterval(timerId);
 var i = 0; // a simple counter
 timerId = setInterval(function () {
   if (i > times) // if the last frame is reached, set counter to zero
   {  i = 0;
        clearInterval(timerId);}
        else
      element.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -" + i * height + 'px'; //scroll up
      i++;
    }, 50); // every 50 milliseconds
};
})();
```

HTML (follows same basic template for each element)

```
<a href="./for-sale/" onmouseover="scrollUp(42, 9, document.getElementById('sp-58'))">
  For Sale
  <div id="sp-58" class="sparkleparty"></div>
</a>
```

Comment: Could you tell us which browsers you need to support? You could use css3 transitions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you really need is to use separate **timerId**-s for each animation.
It is a matter of scopes and closures, really. In the provided example, **timerId** is sort of global for all **scrollUp(...)** functions. To fix this you can try this:

```
var scrollUp = function (height, times, element) {
 var i = 0; // a simple counter
 var timerId = setInterval(function () {
  if (i > times) {
   i = 0; clearInterval(timerId);
  } else {
   element.style.backgroundPosition = "0px -" + i * height + 'px'; //scroll up
  }
  i++;
 }, 50); // every 50 milliseconds
};
```

Comment: I believe requestAnimationFrame is better

Answer (score 0):

I created a simple library for this for this. Check it out: https://github.com/wolthers/SpriteClip.js